# Getting an error when trying to save React DOM to PDF using jsPDF

Tags: reactjs, pdf, dom, jspdf

I am trying to render data on the page which works fine, but I want to be able to save whats displaying on the page as a PDF. I have been looking around and found jsPDF and am trying to implement it but not sure where I am going wrong. Would like for someone to help out.

```
  import React from 'react'
  import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
  import { Mutation, Query } from "react-apollo";
  import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
  import { Grid, Button, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'
  import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react- beautiful-dnd'
  import { FlexyFlipCard } from 'flexy-flipcards'
  import jsPDF from 'jspdf'


  import Graphs from './Graphs.jsx'


  const getItems = (count, array) =>
    Array.from({ length: count }, (v, index) => index).map(index => ({
      id: `item-${index}`,
      content: array[index].map((activity) => { return (  
        <div>
          <div>  
            <div style={{float: 'right'}}>{activity.name}</div><br/>
            <div style={{float: 'right'}}>{activity.cost === null || 0 ? 'Free' : activity.cost === 1 ? '$' : activity.cost === 2 ? '$$' : activity.cost === 3 ? '$$$' : activity.cost === 4 ? '$$$$' : null}</div>
            <Image style={{width: '50px', height: '50px'}} src={activity.image}></Image>
          </div> <br/>
        </div>
      )})
    }));

  // a little function to help us with reordering the result
  const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
    const result = Array.from(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);

    return result;
  };

  const grid = 45;

  const getItemStyle = (isDragging, draggableStyle) => ({
    // some basic styles to make the items look a bit nicer
    userSelect: 'none',
    padding: '10px',
    margin: 0,

    // change background colour if dragging
    background: isDragging ? 'lightgreen' : 'white',

    // styles we need to apply on draggables
    ...draggableStyle,
  });

  const getListStyle = isDraggingOver => ({
    background: isDraggingOver ? 'white' : 'white',
    display: 'flex',
    padding: grid,
    overflow: 'auto',
  });

  class Kamban extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super (props)
      this.state = {
        items: getItems(this.props.days.length, this.props.days),
        open: false
      }
      this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this)
    }

    onDragEnd(result) {
      // dropped outside the list
      if (!result.destination) {
        return;
      }

      const items = reorder(
        this.state.items,
        result.source.index,
        result.destination.index
      );

      this.setState({
        items,
      });
    }

    savePDF () {
      const doc = new jsPDF()
      doc.fromHTML(ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<Kamban />), 10, 10, {'width': 180})
      doc.save('text.pdf')
    }


    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <Grid style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
              <Droppable droppableId="droppable" type="app" direction="horizontal">
                {(provided, snapshot) => (
                  <div
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
                    {...provided.droppableProps}
                  >
                    {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                      <div  style={{border: '2px solid gray', height: '700px', width: '300px', marginRight: '10px', float: 'right'}}>
                        <div>
                          {`${index + 50} degrees`}
                        </div>
                        <br/>


                        <Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.id} index={index}>
                          {(provided, snapshot) => (
                            <div
                              ref={provided.innerRef}
                              {...provided.draggableProps}
                              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                              style={getItemStyle(
                                snapshot.isDragging,
                                provided.draggableProps.style
                              )}
                            >
                            <FlexyFlipCard
                                frontBackgroundColor="white"
                                backBackgroundColor="white"
                            >
                                <div >
                                  <div>{item.content}</div>
                                  <Button ref='flipper'>STATS</Button>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  {/* <Graphs></Graphs> */}
                                  <Button ref='flipper'>TRIP</Button>
                                </div>
                            </FlexyFlipCard>
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </Draggable>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                    {provided.placeholder}
                  </div>
                )}
              </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>   
          </Grid>
          <Button onClick = {() => this.savePDF()}>Save</Button>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }


  export default Kamban
```

The function is in the class and the button to call it is close to the bottom

Comment: Please make this clearer for us; when you say "not sure where I'm going wrong" - what exactly is going wrong? Are there errors in the console, white screen, etc?

Comment: I get 

    Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access 
    to  the actual error object in development.

and
   Kamban.jsx?01f3:63 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
   undefined

Comment: The error referring to CORS (cross-origin) is not to do with React at all. Read here for an explanation of CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.